# How to use symfony callback constraint with validation group in yaml?

Tags: validation, symfony

I'm using Symfony 2.6 and I'm following these tutorials how to use the validation callback constraint:

http://symfony.com/blog/new-in-symfony-2-4-a-better-callback-constraint

http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/constraints/Callback.html#external-callbacks-and-closures

To invoke an external validation call I'm trying to use following yaml configuration:

```
App\APIBundle\Entity\Order:
properties:
    id:
        - Type:
            type: integer
            message: "Der Wert {{ value }} ist kein gültiger {{ type }}."
    amount:
        - Type:
            type: integer
            message: "Der Wert {{ value }} ist kein gültiger {{ type }}."
            groups: [ "AppOrder", "AppOrderbasket" ]
        - Callback: [App\APIBundle\Validator\Validator, validate]
            groups: [ "AppOrder", "AppOrderbasket" ]
```

I run into following problems when trying to validate the **amount** property with an **external** callback validation class:

The function "validate" within the validation class App\APIBundle\Validator\Validator doesn't get invoked at all. I've tried to add validation groups by adding the "groups" property to the callback constraint. This seems not to be valid as i get this warning (Warning: trim() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given);

If I remove the "groups" property the warning dissapears but the validator is still not invoked.

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance
ninsky

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are now mixing the [default option syntax](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/validation.html#validation-default-option) with the normal syntax. That doesn't work.

If you only need to specify the default option (which is the `callback` option in case of the `Callback` constraint), you can use `Callback: [App\APIBundle\Validator\Validator, validate]`. However, if you have to define 2 options (in your case `callback` and `groups`), you have to use the normal syntax:

```
- Callback:
    callback: [App\APIBundle\Validator\Validator, validate]
    groups: [AppOrder, AppOrderbasket]
```